# Need help identifying this vintage bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, australia

[image: blake]

I got it out an old farm shed in Mt Pleasant, South Australia. It has a Mansfield seat, and an Eadie coaster rear hub. All I can find out about the frame is that it says Blake on the front. I'm looking for help identifying the model or at least getting a rough idea of the age.

Comment: Look at [this page](https://andrewritchie.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/proletarian-cyclists/), near the center.  The guy wearing a British/Australian style helmet with a gun strung from the bike.  Appears to be the identical bike, based on the chainring and the fenders, though his is a bit taller.  The caption says WWII, but the features of the bike suggest it could date from 1930 or so.

Comment: Check the tires -- they look like they could be glue-on ("tubular") style.  The narrow tires combined with coaster brake suggests a design that predates derailleur gearing in the mid 30s (though of course the actual bike may have been produced after that).  It would make sense for this to be a military bike (as in the picture I linked above), as it would be cheap and reliable and easy to ride, even for the uninitiated.

Comment: You might check with these guys: http://www.sydneycyclist.com/photo/1321712:Photo:1649

Comment: Tyres are one of the things that will almost certainly have been replaced.  The knobs look far more modern than the rest of the bike.

Comment: I don't know much about bikes, the front tire looks a lot older than the rear one. It doesn't have a tread, it's more just a lumpy rubber.